# What capacitance would I need to actuate a solenoid?

Tags: capacitance, solenoid

I have a project that requires I hit a 5 cm ball with a push-pull solenoid.
For the purposes of the project the solenoid needs to be actuated using a capacitor, but after reading multiple forums, I am confused on the farad value the capacitor would need. The solenoid I will be using (JF-0826B-12 on Amazon) is rated for 12 V with a resistance of 6ohms. I don't know the time to activate for the solenoid, I'm not sure if that's needed. I plan on using a 12 V battery and a voltage boost circuit to charge the capacitor to 48 V to get more current draw and a more powerful hit on the ball. Please let me know if more information is needed, this is my first time using the site.

Comment: How much energy do you need to impart to the ball?

Comment: Is this a contest where you are attempting to fly the ball as far as possible? How many solenoids do you have? Are you willing to stress some until they fail? This may be the best method; the calculations will be difficult.

Comment: You will need to store much more energy (0.5CV^2) in your capacitor than your ball eventually gains (mgh height or 0.5mv^2 velocity), maybe by a factor of 10 as solenoids are horribly inefficient.

Comment: solenoids don;t respond to mechanically to  energy they respond to current half CV squared will not describe behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a capacitor that's big enough,

Assume 60% efficiency and that force is proprotional to solenoid current
figure out how much impulse * you need to put into the ball-armature  system **  and then convert that to charge *** and pick a capacitor that can store that much charge. This wont be perfect but should get you into the ballpark.

* the time integral of force

** this iimplies that you need to add armature mass and ball mass.

*** the time integral of current

Over currenting the solenoid may not gain you much extra force,  once the metal is saturated with field lines extra current will do nothing.
and an engineer at the manufacturer has probably trimmed all the extra metal to save money.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your numbers, the peak capacitor voltage is 48 V and the peak solenoid current is 8 A.  This sets an absolute limit on how much energy is available to the system.  Whether or not this is enough for the task is a separate problem.

After a few milliseconds, all of the mechanical energy transfer is over and less than 2 A will hold the solenoid in the activated position.  Let's assume a solenoid dropout voltage of 8 V, for a dropout current (using Ohm's Law) of 1.33 A

For a ballpark guess, use a linear (constant current) approximation of the capacitor discharge,

E x C = I x t

C = (I x t) / E

E = capacitor discharge voltage range.  Let's say from 48 V to 8 V = 40

I = average solenoid current over the period.  From 8 A to 1.33 A averages to 4.667

t = discharge time period.  Estimate 20 ms = 0.02

(4.667 x 0.02) / 40 = 2334 uF

This type of linear approximation for an exponential function can be off by around 10% to 15% depending on how much of the exponential curve is being approximated.  In this case it is greater than one time constant, because from 48V to 8 V is 83%, while one time constant is 63%.  Bumping the error estimate up to 20% for margin, the estimated capacitor size increases to 2800 uF.  I would start with 3300 uF and see how it performs.

NOTE: electrolytic capacitors do *not* like large, fast current spikes, either charging or discharging.  This is why photographic flash circuits use specially-built caps.  The cap size might have to be increased to compensate for internal inductance.

UPDATE:  Another, more accurate approach -

The percentage of cap discharge is 83.3%, and two time constants is 86.5%.  We can use this for a closer-to-true-exponential estimate.

To discharge to 2 time constants in 20 ms,

t = 2 x R x C

C = t / (2 x R)

t = 20 ms

R = 6 ohms

C = .02 / 12 = 1667 uF

That is a surprisingly low value, so I'd start with 2200 uF.

UPDATE 2:  Size matters.

There is no penalty for using a larger cap than these calculations indicate.  Discharging into a constant 6 ohm load, a larger cap means that the cap voltage decreases more slowly.  Thus, another approach is to maximize the coil current during the time of physical contact.

Despite how fast a 2 A solenoid armature will move given an 8 A pulse, it still moves at a finite velocity.  And when it encounters resistance, it slows down.  How much is slows depends on the coil current, which depends on the capacitor voltage.  In the above examples, most of the cap energy is delivered to the coil, so after 20 ms the cap is pretty much depleted.  That is size-efficient, but it also means that for the second 10 ms, the coil current was much less than 8 A.

Let's take a different approach.  To get the max force throughout the contact period, the coil current needs to remain high.  Instead of decreasing 6 A over 20 ms, what about having it decrease only 1 A over 8 ms.  This is a short section of a much longer exponential decrease, so short that the linear approximation is much more accurate.

A decrease of only 1 A means the average current over the period is now 7.5 A, and the cap voltage decreases only 6 V.  This is a much larger electrical jolt to the solenoid.

C = (I x t) / E

C = (7.5 x 0.008) / 6 = 10,000 uF

That is a much larger cap, delivering much more energy during the period of interest.  It keeps discharging into the coil until it is depleted, but that is just waste heat that does not affect the system.  In less than 0.4 s the cap is discharged, so coil heating should not be a problem.

I think this is a better approach to the problem.  Once you have an approximate idea of how much time the solenoid is actually doing the work, you can trade off the mechanical punch versus size and cost.

Comment: *After a few milliseconds, all of the mechanical energy transfer is over ...* Or course, I should have thought of this.